# Make a new column that contains the log of the NOx concentration

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKxAF.png)

How do I:
Make a new column that contains the log of the NOx concentration
Summarise the log NOx concentrations by calculating their daily mean. Storing the results in a new dataframe

Comment: Please add more info on your question, separate your problems, and add code samples. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which will help you asking in a correct way.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, SO is not a personal helpdesk for homework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use

```
df1$lNOx <- log(df1$Nox)
aggregate(lNOx ~ Date, df1, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
          mutate(lNox = log(Nox)) %>%
          group_by(Date) %>%
          summarise(lNox = mean(lNox, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: How do I use quantile to solve this?                                              
Below what value do 5% of the daily mean log NOx concentrations lie?Above what value do 5% of the daily mean log NOx concentrations lie?

Comment: @AshLinke  You can use `quantile` to find out

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to work it out using the quantile function could you show me how please?

Comment: i.e. once we create the mean value summarised column `v1 <- quantile(df2$lNox, probs =0.5); df2$lNox < v1`

Comment: Thanks heaps. How would I find the confidence interval at 90% for μ? assuming daily mean log NOx data is normally distributed where Y ~ N( μ, σ^2)

Comment: @AshLinke  You can check [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/interval-estimation/interval-estimate-population-mean-unknown-variance)